# How to get a css animation to transition quicker in keyframes

Tags: html, css, animation

I created a css animation that uses three different images and then at the end I have it go back to the first image. My issue is whenever the image transitions, it doesn't seem natural. It looks as if the old image fades out and the new image fades in simultaneously. I am looking to tighten up the transitions so there is still a little bit of fade, but much quicker and more natural.

I have the percents set for the images, so I am not even sure where the fades are coming from.

Does anyone know how can I do this?

```css
#contact-success-animation {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto auto;
 -webkit-animation-name: success-animation; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 15s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 animation-name: success-animation;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes success-animation {
    0%   {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/smiley-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    33%  {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/big-smile-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    66%  {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/wink-smile-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    100% {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/smiley-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes success-animation {
    0%   {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/smiley-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    33%  {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/big-smile-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    66%  {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/wink-smile-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    100% {background-image: url("http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/smiley-face.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto; height: 100px; width: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-success-animation"></div>
```

Comment: Can you just speed up the whole animation by shortening the `animation-duration`?

Comment: You can speed up the animation, like @JonathanLam said. Also keep in mind that when you set something at `0%` and something else at `33%`, it's not going to just snap to that image after 33% of the time, its going to slowly transition between those two states that you've specified.

Comment: I am fine with the duration. I just want to know how to shorten the transition between the two images. I want it to be one image and then a very quick fade out/fade in to the next image. Not a whole second of transition.

Comment: Ok, so let's focus on the first one. If, at `30%` you set the same thing you set at `0%`, it will transition much quicker. You can do the same thing recursively for all the images to get a "snap" or quicker transition between each one.

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Paul Here, check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/orksnw91/. If I have the previous color (in your case, replace color with images) blocked out, eg. by setting that color to `0%` up to `23%`, it will stay that color until 23% of the time, then transition to my 33% set color. Keep in mind I didn't use the `-webkit` extension in that example, so if you're browser is older and needs that prefix, that Fiddle won't work.

Comment: Ok, so you added more keyframes, but isn't there a way to do this without more keyframes? I only have the three images.

Comment: No, that's just the way that keyframes work. You could write a SASS mixin that generates them automatically, but that's the only thing I could think of to improve the workflow there.

Comment: I have no idea what a SASS mixin is. Can't I just do somewthing like 0%-33% for one image, then 34%-66%, for the next and so on?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I read your question wrong. You can specify `33%` for a state, or `33%,50%` to specify a range to concatinate the information a little: https://jsfiddle.net/gc7v9gL5/1/

Comment: So, by shortening the duration, that is really the only way to eliminate the slow fade? The concatination didn't work like I hoped it would...https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=sLtebHEK0p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `@keyframes`, you can specify "zones" of time by writing `33%,65%` instead of `33%`. This allows you to block out periods of time where one image will be on the screen, and then it quickly transitions to another after a time, which will achieve what you're looking for.

Here's an example, using background colors, instead of images ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gc7v9gL5/1/)):

### HTML

```
<div class="Snappy">
  This is a snappy transition.
</div>
<div class="Smooth">
  This is a smooth transition.
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.Smooth
{
  animation: smoothColors 10s infinite;
}

.Snappy
{
  animation: snappyColors 10s infinite;
}

/* Keyframes */

@keyframes smoothColors{
  0%{background: #ff0000;}
  33%{background: #00ff00;}
  66%{background: #0000ff;}
  100%{background: #ff0000;}
}

@keyframes snappyColors{
  0%,23%{background: #ff0000;}
  33%,56%{background: #00ff00;}
  66%, 90%{background: #0000ff;}
  100%{background: #ff0000;}
}
```